# Obtener fecha de los días viernes con python

Tags: python, date, scraping

buen día.

Debo obtener la fecha de todos los viernes dos semanas atrás del día actual y dos semanas adelante.  Me explico:

Hoy es viernes 16/07/2021, debo obtener la fecha del viernes de hace dos semanas antes, la cual debe ser: 02/07/2021. y la de dos semanas adelante, la cual debe ser: 30/07/2021.

La siguiente semana, independiente del día(de lunes a domingo) debo obtener la fecha del viernes de dos semanas atrás(09/07/2021) y dos semanas después(06/08/2021).

tengo este código, sin embargo con él, obtengo las fechas de 15 días antes y 15 días después de la fecha actual, lo cual no me sirve, ya que es cambiante. Debo obtener únicamente las fechas de los días viernes. No sé si me hago entender, espero que si, soy un poco nuevo en esto y no he podido encontrar la forma de obtener esta información, les agradezco de antemano :).

```
#fechas
yesterday = date.today() + timedelta(days=-1)
now = datetime.now() # Fecha y hora actual de ejecución
    
#para los 15 dias anteriores a la fecha actual
anterior = now + timedelta(days=-15)
antes = datetime.strftime(anterior,"%d/%m/%Y").lstrip('0')
#para los 15 días despues de la fecha actual
posterior = now + timedelta(days=+15)
después = datetime.strftime(posterior,"%d/%m/%Y").lstrip('0')


#ingresamos fecha de inicio
fechainicio = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Date Start"]/following::input')
fechainicio.send_keys(str(antes))
time.sleep(5)

#ingresamos fecha de fin
fechafin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Date End"]/following::input')
fechafin.send_keys(str(despues))
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**El razonamiento sería el siguiente:**

1. Me paro en la fecha actual (hoy), y pido el día de la semana al que corresponde 
   (con el lunes = 0 y domingo = 6)
2. Busco la fecha del viernes correspondiente a la semana en curso (día 4 de la semana)
3. Desde ahí, pido la fecha de 14 días atrás y 14 días adelante.

Bueno, el paso número 3 ya lo tenés resuelto (salvo porque necesitás moverte 14 días en cada dirección, no 15), lo que te está faltando lo podrías hacer con algo así:

```
import datetime

# Busco el viernes de la semana actual
hoy = datetime.date.today()
vie = hoy + datetime.timedelta(4 - hoy.weekday())

# Desde aquí tu código, fijate que reemplazo now por vie

#para los 14 dias anteriores a la fecha actual
anterior = vie + datetime.timedelta(days=-14)
antes = datetime.datetime.strftime(anterior,"%d/%m/%Y").lstrip('0')
#para los 14 días despues de la fecha actual
posterior = vie + datetime.timedelta(days=+14)
después = datetime.datetime.strftime(posterior,"%d/%m/%Y").lstrip('0')
```

Y eso sería todo, para más información podés leer en la documentación oficial de python acerca de [datetime](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html) y tal vez también te podría servir leer sobre el módulo [calendar](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/calendar.html#module-calendar) y [time](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/time.html#module-time).

Espero que te sirva, ¡saludos!

Comment: Hola, me funcionó perfecto! muchisimas gracias, te lo agradezco :)

Comment: ¡Un placer Carlos!